# Data transfer in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm currently working on a project that has multiple stages to set up a certain thing. In stage one, the user provides a Title, Description, and a required int value. I need to do two things with this data:

1. Take the title, and set it as the ActionBar title. This is not hard by any means. I've simply set the variable that the Title value was stored in as an extra on the intent, and retrieved it in the new activity, and set it using the .setTitle(); method on the ActionBar.

Here's the one I need help with...

2. I need to get that integer value transferred over so I can use it as the number returned by the SectionsPagerAdapter, so when it calls `getCount();` it returns the value.

I can get the value inside of the same Class as the Title value, but cannot seem to get it in the SectionsPagerAdapter.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can put this counter in SharedPreferences and recover it in your getCount() method. I don't what exactly you need because I can't understand completely your question.

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences to store data that will be shared among all app activities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternately you can extend SectionsPagerAdapter and include a setter for that value or use a convenience constructor.

Something like this:

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private int mPageCount;

    /**
     * 
     * @param pageCount
     */
    public CustomPagerAdapter(int pageCount) {
        this.mPageCount = pageCount;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mPageCount;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? When I try to edit the SectionsPagerAdapter method "getCount" to take an int param, it doesn't work.

Comment: Edited. Without seeing your existing adapter it's a little difficult to be exact. Basically the adapter can go out and get the int data either through Context or Shared Preferences or it can have the int data put into it via constructor or a public set method.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know clearly your problem, but before you change page or when you have value, you can use this class:

```
  Class SavedDave extends Application(){
   private static  String data;
   //Contructor
   ....
   public void SetData(String value){
      this.data = value;
   }
   public String getData(){
      return data;
   }
}
```

By this class, you can set and get your value every where when application running, is it solve your problem?

Answer (score -1):

Suppose your method in activity is named getTitle();

From adapter call it like context.getTitle();

where context would be one you pass to the constructor of adapter

```
private final Context context;

public DataPagerAdapter( Context context )
{
    this.context = context;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). This is the recommended way to do it in Android.

```
@SharedPref
public interface ExamplePrefs {

    // The name will have default value of "Anonymous"
    @DefaultString("Anonymous")
    String name();

    // The field age will have default value 42
    @DefaultInt(42)
    int age();

    // The field address will have default value of "MyAddress"
    @DefaultString("MyAddress")
    String name();

    // The field lastUpdated will have default value 0
    long lastUpdated();

}
```

For your use case just create a class SectionsPagerPref as follows :

```
@SharedPref
public interface SectionsPagerPref {
    @DefaultInt(0)
    int getCount();
}
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Please avoid link-based answers next time.

Comment: Thank you. I figured this question was begging for using Shared Preferences and so i thought i would give it a go.